# How do I create a title bar with some text to the left and some to the right?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using jquery widgets and I need to create a title with some text to the left of the title bar and some to the right.  Here is a snippet:

```
    <div id="newtask" class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default">
    <h4 class="ui-widget-header">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-done">New Task</span> Todo <div style="text-align:right">This needs 
    </h4>
```

However, the right hand text is displaced one line below the left hand.  How do I get one single line with some text to the left and some to the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use float:right...

```
    <div id="newtask" class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default">
    <h4 class="ui-widget-header">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-done">New Task</span> Todo <div style="float:right;">This needs 
    </h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Float the text you want to appear on the left to the left, and float the text you want to appear on the right to the right.

Alternatively, position the text you want to appear on the left absolutely to the left (with the parent positioned relative) and position the text you want to appear on the right absolutely to the right.