# Format some text to the left, some text to the right, on the same time

Tags: css, arabic

I checked [prior posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693862/how-do-i-create-a-title-bar-with-some-text-to-the-left-and-some-to-the-right) and still can't get this working. How do you align translations of a text *on the same line* to the left and to the right? I work with both Arabic and English. Thought about trying to use a table and some CSS, but how?

```
<table width="100%"><tr><td height="30px">
3) What services do you provide?
</td>
<td class="arabic">
ما هي الخدمات التي تقدّمها؟
</td></tr></table>
```

3) What services do you provide? ما هي الخدمات التي تقدّمها؟

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show text from Right to Left you can use [**direction**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction) property.

> Set the direction CSS property to match the direction of the text: rtl for languages written from right-to-left (like Hebrew or Arabic) text and ltr for other scripts.

```css
.arabic {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td height="30px">
      3) What services do you provide?
    </td>
    <td class="arabic">
      ما هي الخدمات التي تقدّمها؟
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can also use `float` to make the text render to the right.

```css
.arabic {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td height="30px">
      3) What services do you provide?
    </td>
    <td class="arabic">
      ما هي الخدمات التي تقدّمها؟
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```